# Evaluate multiple conditions stored as a string withput eval method

Tags: php, eval

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "0 || 0 && 1";
```

actually this string is a condition. 
if i do like this :

```
if($str) {
  echo "done";
}
else {
echo "sfcsd";
}
```

it is always true since `$str` is string.

How can i evaluate this string with out eval().

Comment: Is this just simple || and && operators, or anything ore complex? Do you need to handle bracketing, e.g `(0 || 0) && 1` or `0 || (0 && 1)`?

Comment: i just need above string to executed.

Comment: dear friends it is not the same what you have mark as alias of this question. i do not wanted to use eval.

Comment: @AwladLiton I think it is either that or building yourself a simple class for it to build and/or parse the conditions/string.

Answer (score 0):

check out sandboxing in PHP. here is a quick tutorial:

http://www.fieryprophet.com/blog/detail/sandboxing-untrusted-code-with-phpsandbox